# Using subquery to compare the price column with the average price of the categories

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to use two tables (categories and products) to generate a table with the category_name and product_price. The product_price variable should be the list price that is greater than the average price of the product in the specific category.I have to use the subquery to generate this table.

The subquery is written in the WHERE clause which compares the price with the average price of each category. Both the main Select statement and the subquery seem to be working perfectly separately. However,  when I try to run them altogether, the table generates all the prices, not only the ones that are greater than the avg price per category. Also, when I use the ALL command instead of Any, it only return 2 rows for one category. It doesn't return the other 2 rows from the other categories that I am expecting. Is there any thing that I am missing here?

Comment: You should just get rid of the `ANY` keyword, that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: @Josh why did you remove the code from your question? If it is not relevant to your problem then edit the question and explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
WHERE p.list_price > (SELECT AVG(p2.list_price)
                      FROM products p2
                      WHERE p2.category_id = p.category_id
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want:

```
SELECT p.product_name, c.category_name, p.list_price
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN categories c ON p.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE p.list_price > (
    SELECT AVG(p1.list_price) FROM products p1 WHERE on p1.category_id = p.category_id     
)
```

The correlated subquery gives you the average price of all products within the same category. This returns a *scalar* value, so there is no need for a set-based operator such as `ALL` or `ANY`.

Also please note that your original query had conflicting table aliases between then subquery and the outer query (`p` and `c` were used in both context), which were creating ambiguity about which table the aliases in the subquery did relate to.

Finally: if you are running MySQL 8.0 (or a version of SQLite that supports window functions), you can get the same result with a window average:

```
SELECT product_name, category_name, list_price
FROM (
    SELECT 
        p.product_name, 
        c.category_name, 
        p.list_price, 
        AVG(list_price) OVER(PARTITION BY c.category_id) avg_list_price
    FROM products p 
    INNER JOIN categories c ON p.category_id = c.category_id
) t
WHERE list_price > avg_list_price
```